# Variable losing its allocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I cant figure out why I am getting this error and would appreciate some guidance.

I am setting a variable in the `viewDidLoad` method and the `NSLog` returns the expected result from `_myUser.email` and `_myUser`.

Now, when I call the `_myUser` variable in any `(IBAction)`method it always crashes the app. I think is because it loses it allocation. Otherwise I cant explain why it crashes the app if executed anywhere else. But then again... I am doing everything I know that would ensure that the variable is available & setted across the app.

I've searched across the app and the only place where i set `_myUser` is in the `viewDidLoad`, so its not that I am unsetting it anywhere else

**edit**: if I call `[self myOtherMethod]` from the very end of `ViewDidLoad` the `NSLog` will works but not from inside any other method.

**edit2** it works in another part of the app when i do exactly the same thing

`User` is a `NSManagedObject` object
`Model` is a `NSObject` where i have all my model queries.

the crash is a simple `(lldb)`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) User* myUser;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _model = [[model alloc]init];
    _myUser = [User alloc]; // I can do this or not do it and it gives me the same result
    _myUser = [_model getCurrentUser];

     NSLog(@"First: %@",_myUser.email);
}
- (void) myOtherMethod {
NSLog(@"Second: %@",_myUser.email);
}
```

Comment: can you post what the console says on the crash?

Comment: @CodaFi I put the Alloc as a way to see if it was the lack of it what was causing the proble,

Comment: @Chuck yes I am using that

Comment: (lldb) is not very informative. and the crashing point is the execution point of the _myUser in NSLog

Comment: Your line [User alloc] isn't needed because you're overriding that variable with [_model getCurrentUser] in the very next line. Also if you want to use the _myUser instance variable, you should synthesize your property with: @synthesize myUser = _myUser;. Two questions: 1) If you changed myOtherMethod to NSLog(@"Second: %@", _myUser), does that still break? 2) Can you make sure email is a strong property of the User object?

Comment: @Mr.T `@synthesize myUser = _myUser;` is no longer needed; that code is generated by default.

Comment: @CRD, It doesn't look like he's using MRC.  The property is "strong", not "retain".

Comment: @Mr.T 1) yes Still breaks. 2) that comes from CoreData. Fun fact same method accessed in the same way works in a different part of the app.

Comment: Wait, is `email` a relationship to another managed object, or a property?

Comment: Is _model still around?  Is that a "strong" property?  Test this by changing myOtherMethod to NSLog(@"Second: %@", _model);

Comment: if i do `[_model getCurrentUser]` it still works in he other method

Comment: Show us `-getCurrentUser` then.

Comment: i'm out of ideas... haha, try turning on Zombie Objects (hit Command-Shift-,   then go to Diagnostics for Debug and Enable Zombie Objects) and see if it gives you any meaningful debug output....

Comment: this is what '_myUser'  throws  `Second1: <User: 0xf101760> (entity: User; id: 0xf11c9f0 <x-coredata://DAACA9F9-423C-4B53-A924-10A60F07FD23/User/p1> ; data: <fault>)`

Comment: @Mr.T if I enable `Zombie Object` no more crashes. `email` return `null` but `_myUser` returns an entity `Second1: <User: 0xa3393f0> (entity: User; id: 0xa336170 <x-coredata://DAACA9F9-423C-4B53-A924-10A60F07FD23/User/p0> ; data: <fault>)`

Comment: k, well, so it seems your user entity is in the fault state that can't seem to fetch its data from the store... i'm not sure why it's only happening at this point, but can you try setting your request to not return objects as faults (ie. force it to fetch data once you make your request) and see what happens. i believe the command is something like [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

Comment: @Mr.T: `strong` and `retain` are synonyms. You can use `strong` under any compiler that supports ARC, even if you are not using ARC.

Comment: Also, it's better to use Instruments's Zombies template than Xcode's zombies option. In Instruments, you can examine the history of the zombie object, to determine why it died prematurely.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _model = [[model alloc]init];

    self._myUser = [[_model getCurrentUser] retain];

     NSLog(@"First: %@",self._myUser.email);
}
- (void) myOtherMethod {
NSLog(@"Second: %@",self._myUser.email);
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];

        _model = [[model alloc]init];

        _myUser = [[_model getCurrentUser] retain]; // or copy if you owerdrive copyWithZone: metod

         NSLog(@"First: %@",_myUser.email);
    }
    - (void) myOtherMethod {
    NSLog(@"Second: %@",_myUser.email);
    }
```

Comment: `self._myUser` is wrong... `self.myUser` is the right way..... but anyways.. the `retain` at the end made the trick...`_myUser = [[_model getCurrentUser] retain];`

Comment: @JonathanThurft: You said you were using ARC. If you can compile this code, you aren't using ARC.

Comment: As the questioner said, `self._myUser` is wrong; the property is named `myUser`, the instance variable is named `_myUser`, and `self.…` accesses a property, not (directly) an instance variable. The latter example is right, but the former needs one fewer underscore. It also needs one fewer `retain` message: When you assign to a `strong` property, the property's setter method will retain the object. `retain`ing it beforehand means it gets retained twice, and so will be leaked.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> _myUser = [User alloc]; // I can do this or not do it and it gives me the same result
> _myUser = [_model getCurrentUser];
> ```

Never call `[SomeClass alloc]` without immediately sending the result an `init` (or any variation thereof) message. An allocated but not initialized object is dangerous; anything may happen when you try to use it.

In this code, it doesn't make any difference because you immediately replace the User object you just created (but didn't initialize) with the one you get from `[_model getCurrentUser]`.

The variable and the object are two different things. The variable is part of whatever object you've declared this property in (looks like some kind of view controller), and is a container that contains a reference to another object, which is the User object you're getting from the model. The variable is not “losing its allocation”; the User object is.

This is also why it doesn't make sense to say anything like:

```
_myUser = [[User alloc] init]; //This statement is unnecessary!
_myUser = [_model getCurrentUser];
```

The first line creates a new User object that doesn't have anything to do with anything, and stores a reference to it in your `_myUser` variable, and the second line then *immediately* replaces that reference to that object with a reference to a different User object—the “current user” that you get from the model. One variable, two objects.

> the crash is a simple `(lldb)`

“`(lldb)`” isn't a kind of crash; it's the debugger's prompt. You need to look above the prompt to see what kind of crash it is.

It may also help to look at the stack trace in the Navigator and see exactly on which line(s) of your code the crash occurred.

[Added] Or type `bt` into that prompt, if you don't have anything in the Navigator. (Apparently, LLDB kicking in without Xcode noticing is a bug that's started appearing as of 10.8.4, according to a couple of other SO questions I've seen.)

> the `retain` at the end made the trick...

Then you are not using ARC. You can't send `retain` messages under ARC, so if you can send a `retain` message and your build succeeds, that proves that you are not using ARC.

That, in turn, suggests what the problem was: You assigned that User object that you got from `getCurrentUser` to your instance variable, but since you didn't retain it or assign it to a `strong` property, it died out from under you, and since you were still holding onto it, you crashed sometime later when you tried to use that dead object.

I recommend turning on ARC. Then, you would not need (or be able) to retain the object; merely assigning it to an instance variable such as `_myUser` would do the job of keeping the object alive.

One alternative is the solution you picked (`retain`ing the object yourself); the other would be to assign the object to the `myUser` property (`self.myUser`) rather than the `_myUser` instance variable. As long as you're not using ARC, merely assigning to an instance variable does not retain the object; assigning to a `strong` property does, as does `retain`ing the object yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A decent rule of thumb, especially for new Objective-C programmers, is to always use properties instead of instance variables, and to only reference the _instanceVariable in the getter and setter.

Comment: I think this is the wrong way of thinking about it.  Properties are, and always have been, wrappers around iVars (which are just memory offsets in an internal struct).  A beginner should know that, and understand the consequences of assignment, rather than assuming hand-waving and magic with setters.